# entity Framework dotnet 6 startup

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a discord bot using Discord.net. the connection to the bot is all right, now I'm trying to connect a database
I would like to add the database with entity framework but i never worked that way in dotnet6. Would you help me?

I'm using the HRKing template https://github.com/HRKings/DiscordNetBotTemplate

I tried:

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ArmarioBot.Services;
using ContaCentral.Infrastructure.Data.Context;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ArmarioBot;

public class Startup
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;

    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddDbContext<MySQLContext>();

    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        await using var services = ConfigureServices();
        _client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();

        
            
        _client.Ready += OnReady;
        _client.Log += LogAsync;
        services.GetRequiredService<CommandService>().Log += LogAsync;


        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "TOKENBOT");
        await _client.StartAsync();

        await services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandlingService>().InitializeAsync();

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private Task OnReady()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Connected to these servers as '{_client.CurrentUser.Username}': ");
        foreach (var guild in _client.Guilds)
            Console.WriteLine($"- {guild.Name}");

        _client.SetGameAsync("I'm alive!", type: ActivityType.CustomStatus);
        Console.WriteLine($"Activity set to '{_client.Activity.Name}'");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static Task LogAsync(LogMessage log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        return new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<DiscordSocketClient>()
            .AddSingleton<CommandService>()
            .AddSingleton<CommandHandlingService>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
namespace ArmarioBot;

public static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        new Startup().Initialize().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

MySqlContext.cs

```
using ArmarioBot.Domain.Model;
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ContaCentral.Infrastructure.Data.Context
{
    public class MySQLContext : DbContext
    {
        public MySQLContext(DbContextOptions<MySQLContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Does `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` get called? Where is your code that makes use of your MySQLContext?